# ReactJS: How to unregister RouteLeaveHook after Unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm currently programming frontend for 1 education page. It has many lessons which defined by route `/:id`, and at the end of each lesson may have a quiz test or not!

If a lesson have quiz test, i will setRouteLeaveHook to ask user to continue navigate from current page or not:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.context.route, this.routerWillLeave);
},
routerWillLeave: function (route) {
    console.log("router will leave");
    if (this.state.started) {
        this.handleOpenDialog(route);
        return false;
    }
},
```

It seems that after user change to other lesson, the hook is not destroyed yet, and it keeps printing "router will leave" each time user navigate. And when user navigate to another lesson which have quiz test, too, browser warn this:

> Warning: [react-router] adding multiple leave hooks for the same route is deprecated; manage multiple confirmations in your own code instead

How can I unregister the hook after the component is unmounted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution on [API Doc](https://github.com/nvartolomei/react-router/blob/12022db006c97b30ba27d1a6af25296db73be74c/docs/API.md#setrouteleavehookroute-hook):

> **setRouteLeaveHook(route, hook)**
>
> Returns a function that may be used to unbind the listener.

So, I just call the function that return when setRouteLeaveHook like this:

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    this.setState({
        removeLeaveHook: this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.context.route, this.routerWillLeave)
    });
},
componentWillUnmount: function () {
    if (this.state.removeLeaveHook)
        this.state.removeLeaveHook();
},
```

It works!